# Excluding Types in the Generic Constraints (Possible?)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

Is possible to exclude specific types from the set of possible types, that can be used in a generic parameter?  If so how.

For example

```
Foo<T>() : where T != bool
```

would mean any type except for the type bool.

**Edit**

Why?

The following code is my attempt to enforce the negative constraint.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var x1=Lifted.Lift("A");
      var x2=Lifted.Lift(true);
    }
    static class Lifted
    {
      // This one is to "exclude" the inferred type variant of the parameter
      [Obsolete("The type bool can not be Lifted", true)]
      static public object Lift(bool value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
      // This one is to "exclude" the variant where the Generic type is specified.
      [Obsolete("The type bool can not be Lifted", true)]
      static public Lifted<T> Lift<T>(bool value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
      static public Lifted<T> Lift<T>(T value) { return new Lifted<T>(value); }
    }

    public class Lifted<T>
    {
      internal readonly T _Value;
      public T Value { get { return this._Value; } }
      public Lifted(T Value) { _Value = Value; }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it involves a bit of faith in the overload resolution being correct, and bit of @jonskeet -esque evil code.

Comment out the section with deals with the inferred type example and it doesn't work.

It would be so much better to have the excluded generic constraint.

Comment: What would be the use?  `where T : x` means `T` has the capabilities of `x`. A negative constraint seems meaningless.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See updated edit on original post.

Comment: @AdamSpeight And what happens when someone does `var liftedBool = Lifted.Lift((object) false); bool liftedBoolValue = (bool)liftedBool.Value;`

Comment: Would be accepted because it been cast, and subsequent use would be Object till you re-cast it back to a bool.

Comment: I asked a similar question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422625/is-there-any-programming-language-with-an-exclusion-type-system

Comment: re: "A negative constraint seems meaningless" "Why would you want to do that?"

One example I'm running into now - Because `SomeMethod<T>() where T : Base` exists, and I am adding `SomeDerivedMethod<T>() where T : Derived` which will do additional work.
I want the compiler to flag all usage of `SomeMethod<Derived>()` as errors.

Leaning on compiler errors for refactors is a common and important use case.

A work-around for my situation could be to refactor `Base` and `Derived` to share a common base - `ActualBase`. Not an option for the OP though, because T for them are builtin types.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, you can't make one-off exclusions like that using type constraints. You can do it at runtime though:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
     if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
     {
         //throw exception or handle appropriately.
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of checking generic types at run-time, when there maybe a possibility the compiler can enforce it at compile-time.

Comment: @AdamSpeight What you are currently asking for is not possible. Types should be constrained to what they *can* be, not what they cannot be.

Comment: Since in F# you can restrict it `: not struct`

Comment: @AdamSpeight F#'s `not` doesn't work everywhere, only on `struct`. You can't say `not bool` in F#. The `not struct` is the same as C#'s `Foo<T>() where T:class`. Yes, this is a CLR restriction.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the Compile Time checking version I currently have implement. Be warned it's NSFP (Not Safe For Production)

Comment: Just throw a NotSupportedException in the constructor if T is boolean,  any decent programmer (someone who will test his stuff at least once) will get the message and won't use bool.

Comment: It might be more helpful to use overloads, since throwing an exception will only occur at runtime, and it might be useful to know about this behavior when you are writing the code.

Comment: "Types should be constrained to what they can be, not what they cannot be." Reading OP's code you'd see that if he could constrain `T` to match only `bool` then it would work the same but restricting the other method. And yes this is related to having a more robust use of the type system at compile time, which leads to writing less test, and so on.