# is there any way to use generic class/method with 2 type that will not be the same?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-constraints

I can create a generic class and use "where" statement like:

```
public class TestClass<T> where T: IDisposable
{
    .... 
}
```

To be sure that the type "T" is implement the interface 'IDisposable'.

Is there some way to create generic class with 2 types that constrain the types to be different from one another like:

```
public class TestClass<T,K> where T!=K
{
    .... 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No. Question is - why do you want that?

Comment: It's not possible. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642751/excluding-types-in-the-generic-constraints-possible

Comment: What's the problem with T being equal to K?

Comment: I want to create a Bijection collection. I want to ensure that the value and key are not the same type for be able to user the [] operator without ambiguos but in complination and not in runtime(like checking types in ctor and throw exception in case that they are the same).

Comment: See [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: Not get it - why for the same type of T and K, "the [] operator" would be ambiguos?

Comment: Using the `[]` notation is (IMO) just syntactic candy.  could you solve the problem by using unambiguous methods or properties?

Comment: This sounds like an aspect of the program. 
Perhaps you can consider Aspect Oriented Programming to provide this constraint at compile-time.

[PostSharp][1] should provide this capability.


  [1]: http://www.postsharp.net/architecture/custom-architectural-constraints

Comment: Because i have 2 implemention of this operator(Key to value and value to key)

Comment: In the case T==K you will get compilation error `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties`. Isn't it that you need?