# CS0121 ambiguous method call when calling the indexer of a generic container

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a generic container that can be indexed both ways:

```
class DoubleIndexer<T1, T2>
{
    public T2 this[T1 key] { get => default; set { } }
    public T1 this[T2 key] { get => default; set { } }
}
```

The problem is that I get compile-time errors when I try to use an instance with the same type for T1 and T2:

```
var int_int = new DoubleIndexer<int, int>();
int_int[1] = 13; // CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following
                 // methods or properties: 'DoubleIndexer<T1, T2>.this[T1]'
                 // and 'DoubleIndexer<T1, T2>.this[T2]'
```

There is no problem when the types T1 and T2 are different:

```
var int_string = new DoubleIndexer<int, string>();
int_string[1] = "Hello"; // OK
int_string["Hello"] = 1; // OK

var int_byte = new DoubleIndexer<int, byte>();
int_byte[1] = 13; // OK
int_byte[(byte)13] = 1; // OK
```

Is there any workaround for this problem, or I am forced to change the interface of my generic class?

Comment: Do you not find that ambiguous yourself? What do you even expect the code from your example to do? To call both indexers? One? Randomly?

Comment: @Adrian he's not asking why it's happening, but for a "workaround"

Comment: @Adrian of course it's ambiguous. I am searching for a way to resolve the ambiguity, without changing the interface of my class if possible.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich And the question was what the desired outcome is.  "A workaround" is not sufficient explanation of the desired behavior.  What should the workaround do?

Comment: Indexer in essence is special kind of method. Method overloading implies different set of input parameters or theirs types. From other hand from your explanation it's not clear what you are trying to achieve and why do you need this strange construction.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich There is no "workaround" if one does not know what he actually wants...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Because to figure out at that point that the type will turn out to be unusable would require them to pay some very highly skilled guys to spend some amount of time working on that nearly useless feature (sorry, but honestly, this doesn't come up a whole lot), instead of on something that would benefit millions of actual programmers. It *is* telling you you can't do it. Anyway, you can write named GetT1/SetT1 (etc) methods as workarounds for that case. The ambiguity is resolvable, but it'll require more information than just a type.

Comment: @Adrian I see what you guys are saying, he's not being specific enough about what should happen. I took it that he was looking for ideas of what could happen to deter this problem. For example a workaround could simply be a third method that throws a more intelligible error message. Which would be doable if say negative constraints existed.

Comment: @Servy the workaround should allow the caller to differentiate between the two indexers somehow. This is what I have in mind.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Methods GetT1(), SetT1(), GetT2(), SetT2(). Or write a generic indexer class that gets returned by a named property. It's going to be a bit ugly one way or another, and it'll have to be explicit, and it can't be just based on a type.

Comment: @EdPlunkett GetT1(), SetT1(), GetT2(), SetT2() are awkward. The caller should not have to deal with the generic names of the types. Ideally should have to deal with the specific types of the actual instance he created.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The specific types are `int`, and `int`. They are not distinguishable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias since this would clearly not work if the types are identical, why not check for that in the constructor and don't let the type be instantiated that way?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich You'd want it at compile time, something like [a negative type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642751/excluding-types-in-the-generic-constraints-possible).

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I can't issue a compile-time error in the constructor. I can only throw an exception, which is not very helpful. Also I don't want to introduce this restriction to my class. The caller should be allowed to choose freely the types T1 and T2.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sure, then inherit from 'DynamicObject` and override `TryGetIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround can be based on [explicit interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

**2nd version**

```
public interface IDirectIndex<T1, T2>
{
    T2 this[T1 key] { get; set; }
}

public interface IInvertedIndex<T1, T2>
{
    T1 this[T2 key] { get; set; }
}

internal class DoubleIndexer<T1, T2> : IDirectIndex<T1, T2>, IInvertedIndex<T1, T2>
{
    T2 IDirectIndex<T1, T2>.this[T1 key]
    {
        get => default;
        set { Console.WriteLine($"T2 IDirectIndex<T1, T2>.this[T1 key]: {value}"); }
    }

    T1 IInvertedIndex<T1, T2>.this[T2 key]
    {
        get => default;
        set { Console.WriteLine($"T1 IInvertedIndex<T1, T2>.this[T2 key]: {value}"); }
    }
}
```

Test examples:

```
    var int_string = new DoubleIndexer<int, string>();
    ((IDirectIndex<int, string>)int_string)[1] = "Hello"; // OK
    ((IInvertedIndex<int, string>)int_string)["Hello"] = 1; // OK

    var int_byte = new DoubleIndexer<int, byte>();
    ((IInvertedIndex<int, byte>)int_byte)[1] = 134567; // OK
    ((IDirectIndex<int, byte>)int_byte)[134567] = 41; // OK            

    var int_int = new DoubleIndexer<int, int>();
    ((IInvertedIndex<int, int>)int_int)[1] = 1345; // OK
    ((IDirectIndex<int, int>)int_int)[13] = 5431; // OK
```

---

**1st version**

```
public interface IIndex<T1, T2>
{
    T2 this[T1 key] { get; set; }
}

internal class DoubleIndexer<T1, T2> : IIndex<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 this[T2 key]
    {
        get => default;
        set { Console.WriteLine($"T1 this[T2 key]: {value}"); }
    }

    T2 IIndex<T1, T2>.this[T1 key]
    {
        get => default;
        set { Console.WriteLine($"T2 IIndex<T1, T2>.this[T1 key]: {value}"); }
    }
}
```

Test examples:

```
    var int_string = new DoubleIndexer<int, string>();
    ((IIndex<int, string>)int_string)[1] = "Hello"; // OK
    int_string["Hello"] = 1; // OK

    var int_byte = new DoubleIndexer<int, byte>();
    int_byte[1] = 134567; // OK
    ((IIndex<int, byte>)int_byte)[134567] = 41; // OK            

    var int_int = new DoubleIndexer<int, int>();
    int_int[1] = 1345; // OK
    ((IIndex<int, int>)int_int)[13] = 5431; // OK
```

---

[MSDN Indexers in Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/indexers-in-interfaces):

> the fully qualified name is only needed to avoid ambiguity when the
>   class is implementing more than one interface with the same indexer
>   signature

Comment: Maybe the interfaces should me implemented implicitly, so that casting can be omitted in the more common case of distinguished types.

Comment: Right, it is just a little another view to problem. It looks like that using just one *IInvertedIndex* be enough .

Comment: I can't make it work with one Interface. It seems that both are required (if we want to preserve the ability of omitting the casting for distinguished types).

Comment: Hm, could you test the 1st version of the code in the answer (see last test - *var int_int = new DoubleIndexer<int, int>()*)? It should work, I checked it.

Comment: I don't know what was not working for me, when I checked the first version of your answer. Now that I am testing it again, [it's OK](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VkgNz5).

Answer (score 1):

Coders are used to Dictionary<int, string> which works in one direction Key > Value. Given the language limitation, you should go with an approach that is more intuitive, predictable, and fits in with prior art.

1. **Sub-interface only for the reversed situation**

Code:

```
var lookupByIDReversible = new DoubleIndexer<int, string>();
...
lookupByIDReversible[1] = "hello";
lookupByIDReversible.Reverse["hello"] = 1;
```

You might think of some better language.

I'll leave the implementation up to you.

---

2. **RecordSet-centric with Nx indexers possible**

Another approach entirely, would make use of a recordset pattern that can emit indexers that remain linked to the set. The set is the hub for all indexers.

```
class Message
{
    public int ID;
    public int ToUserID;
    public int FromUserID
    public string MessageBody;
    public DateTime UpdatedAt;
}

var messages = new RecordSet<Message>();
messages.AddRange(...);
var byToUserID = messages.IndexBy(r => r.ToUserID);
byToUserID[7].FromUserID = 8; //Found member assignment
byToUserID[9] = byToUserID[10]; //Assignment (probably not desirable)
var byMessageBody = messages.IndexBy(r => r.MessageBody);
byMessageBody["hello"].ToUserID = 11;

byToUserID[12] = new Message() { MessageBody = "test1", ... }; //Where ToUserID in the supplied object will be overwritten.
byMessageBody["test1"].ToUserID == 12; //Evaluates to true
```

The benefit of this, is you get a semantic API that should be more predictable, but it also scales beyond 2 types.

Comment: Thanks Todd for the answer. These are all viable options!